# Disgreement with Birrell's and Davies' book on QFT in curved space

Tags: quantum-field-theory, greens-functions, propagator, research-level, qft-in-curved-spacetime

In B&D (Birrel and Davies) and more specifically, at the end of Chapter two, the authors define the non-zero temperature Green functions, as
$$G_{\beta}^+(x,x')=\langle{\phi(x)}\phi(x')\rangle_{\beta}
\\G_{\beta}^-(x,x')=\langle{\phi(x')}\phi(x)\rangle_{\beta}$$

Assuming that the chemical potential vanishes, they write down the following property for the aforementioned Green functions
$$G_{\beta}^{\pm}(t,\textbf{x},t',\textbf{x}')=
G_{\beta}^{\mp}(t+i\beta,\textbf{x},t',\textbf{x}')\tag{*}\label{*}$$

And they provide the relevant proof for one of the two cases. It goes as follows
$$G_{\beta}^+(t,\textbf{x},t',\textbf{x}')=
\text{tr}[e^{-\beta H}\phi(x)\phi(x')]/\text{tr}(e^{-\beta H})=
\text{tr}[e^{-\beta H}\phi(x)e^{\beta H}e^{-\beta H}\phi(x')]/\text{tr}(e^{-\beta H})\\=
\text{tr}[\phi(t+i\beta,\textbf{x})e^{-\beta H}\phi(x')]/\text{tr}(e^{-\beta H})\\=
\text{tr}[e^{-\beta H}\phi(x')\phi(t+i\beta,\textbf{x})]/\text{tr}(e^{-\beta H})\\=
G^-_{\beta}(t+i\beta,\textbf{x},t',\textbf{x}')$$

Following the exact same steps for $G^-_{\beta}(x,x')$ leads to a contradiction with $\eqref{*}$. Namely,
$$G_{\beta}^-(t,\textbf{x},t',\textbf{x}')=
\text{tr}[e^{-\beta H}\phi(x')\phi(x)]/\text{tr}(e^{-\beta H})=
\text{tr}[e^{-\beta H}\phi(x')e^{\beta H}e^{-\beta H}\phi(x)]/\text{tr}(e^{-\beta H})\\=
\text{tr}[\phi(t'+i\beta,\textbf{x}')e^{-\beta H}\phi(x)]/\text{tr}(e^{-\beta H})\\=
\text{tr}[e^{-\beta H}\phi(x)\phi(t'+i\beta,\textbf{x}')]/\text{tr}(e^{-\beta H})\\=
G^+_{\beta}(t,\textbf{x},t'+i\beta,\textbf{x}')$$

Equivalently, I can start with $G_{\beta}^+(t-i\beta,\textbf{x},t',\textbf{x}')$ and demonstrate, by following the exact same steps as in the first proof, that
$$G_{\beta}^+(t-i\beta,\textbf{x},t',\textbf{x}')=
G_{\beta}^-(t,\textbf{x},t',\textbf{x}')$$
or equivalently
$$G_{\beta}^-(t,\textbf{x},t',\textbf{x}')=
G_{\beta}^+(t-i\beta,\textbf{x},t',\textbf{x}')$$
which again contradicts $\eqref{*}$!

Does the book contain a mistake or am I missing something? And if, indeed, it is a mistake, what happens with the following result
$$G_{\beta}^{(1)}(t,\textbf{x},t',\textbf{x}')=
G_{\beta}^{(1)}(t+i\beta,\textbf{x},t',\textbf{x}')$$
? How can this result hold if $\eqref{*}$ is wrong?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I didn't read the details of your calculation yet, but I'm not sure the result you found contradicts B&D's result. Why do you think they are contradictory? Both of them seem to say, in different ways, that the Green functions are periodic in imaginary time, with period $\beta$

Comment: Their expression reads $G_{\beta}^-(t,\textbf{x},t',\textbf{x}')=G_{\beta}^+(t+i\beta,\textbf{x},t',\textbf{x}')$, whereas mine (according to my calculations) would be $G_{\beta}^-(t,\textbf{x},t',\textbf{x}')=G_{\beta}^+(t-i\beta,\textbf{x},t',\textbf{x}')$ with a minus sign. Isn't that a problem?